# How can I run .exe files with electron already built?

Tags: javascript, build, electron, exe

I tried these steps:
exec(`"./public/Tools/DJOULECO-CLI-MOUSE/dist/FILE.exe"`);

And this:
exec(`file://${path.join(__dirname, "../build/Tools/DJOULECO-CLI-MOUSE/dist/FILE.exe")}`);

Nothing works

The intention is to run the .exe files with electronic already built because without building the exec(`"./public/Tools/DJOULECO-CLI-MOUSE/dist/FILE.exe"`); it works perfectly